# React Native) Concatenate variable (or JSX element) inside string

Tags: react-native

I am trying to concatenate a variable that I pull with a Redux selector into a string, which ultimately reads a URL.

I seem to be getting the syntax wrong, as I keep getting results for just the string "ticker" or nothing at all.

Could someone advise me on this?

I have tried the following but to no avail:

- 'string ${variable} string';
- {'string' + variable + 'string'}
- 'string' + {variable} + 'string'

My code:

```
const { selectedTicker } = useSelector(navigationSelector.all);


const selectUrl = 'https://openapi.naver.com/v1/search/news.json?query=${selectedTicker}&display=5&start=1&sort=sim';
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Template Literals.
That key above your "Tab" Key. Use That. And then wrap around your string with it.

Here.

```
const selectUrl = `https://openapi.naver.com/v1/search/news.json?query=${selectedTicker}&display=5&start=1&sort=sim`;
```